# Calculating probabilities associated to a random search algorithm

Tags: probability

Assume for simplicity the following problem: $f:(0,1)→\mathbb{R}$ is a function for which we want to find a global minimum, assuming it exists. Our optimization algorithm has one input, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and it works as follows:

1. Pick a random initial point in $(0,1)$ and store it. Set a counter to $0$.
2. If the counter is equal to $n$ return the stored point.
3. Pick a random point in $(0,1)$.
4. If $f$ evaluated at this point is strictly smaller than at our stored point, replace the previously stored point with the new one and set the counter to zero. Otherwise, add an increment of $1$ to the counter.
5. Go back to step 2.

Now, the question: Intuitively speaking, the greater $n$ is, the greater the chance our output being in the "best" 5% (or 1%, or 10%) of points in $(0,1)$ is. But what would be that chance precisely? [In this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160479/practical-hyperparameter-optimization-random-vs-grid-search) a slightly easier problem is described in terms of probabilities. If your algorithm consists of picking a fixed number of points (say, 60) and comparing $f$ evaluated at all of them, then we can calculate the chance of every single one of our picks missing the best 5% of points in our domain.

I tried considering the cumulative distribution function $A(y) = \mu(x \in (0,1) \mid f(x) < y)$. If we fix a point $x_0 \in (0,1)$ and we pick $n$ values in $(0,1)$, then the probability of all these values giving us greater values from $f$ is exactly $(1-A(f(x_0)))^n$. I'm not sure if this solves the problem, though, since by our algorithm if any of these points gives us a smaller $f$ evaluation then we restart our counter.

Answer (score 1):

My very unreliable amateur attempt is to look at just the number of iterations this way:

The probability of finding an extremum with random search over a sorted or unsorted array would be the same, we can imagine we "sorted" the function, the slopes are irrelevant, if the function is never horizontal we might as well consider finding a minimum of f(x)=x.

With our random $x_0$ probability of starting over is $1-(1-x_0)^n$, expected number of added loops is maybe $r=\int_0^1{\frac{(1-(1-x))^n}{x}}dx$? Integrals always get me, I have zero confidence in this part, but the idea of arriving at this r should be sound.

If we found a smaller $x_1\in(0,x_0)$ in n trials with $p=x_0$ probability, it was after $K\in \{ 1,\dots,n \} $ steps and $P(K=k)=x_0(1-x_0)^{k-1}$. As we get closer to the minimum, the distribution of K starts being almost uniform, upper limit of the average number of steps in a restarted loop $\frac{1+n}{2}$, but the first few restarts will most likely be with 1.

I think we can say we tried at least $1+r+n$ random points and one of those points was in the specific 5% interval containing the true minimum with probability $1-(1-0.05)^{1+r+n}$.

Edit: However, the algorithm was considerably more likely to find one of the 5% points that would be closest in value to the minimum.

Comment: Your first assumption, that WLOG we can assume $f(x)=x$, is not that obvious for me. If we take the derivative of $A(y)$ we get wildly different pdfs and that would change the probabilities of getting better or worse points in our domain. However, your approach of breaking the algorithm down into the expected number of added loops (I'm not sure either if the integral is the way to go), finding a new point in each loop in $K$ steps, the expected number of points evaluated, etc. is really helpful.

Comment: If the sorted function is strictly increasing, the probability of randomly finding x in(0,x0) with f(x)<f(x0) will be (x0-0)/1 for any function. Using f(x)=x in my mind makes transitioning into considering following loop easier, since with interchangable argument and probability we use $x_1\sim Uniform(0,x_0)$ to make another binomial trial with p=x1 and (somehow) find the limit of expected number these. Method falls apart if we have for example $f(x)=min(sin(2\pi x),0)$ and the sorted function would be g(x)=0 for x in [0.5,1) and the probability of lower value is not x_0

Comment: Randomly finding x in (0,1). Couldn't edit for some reason. Hope it helps.